# How can I deploy an Uno Web assembly application

Tags: uno-platform

We are not able to find the deployment documentation regarding Uno Web assembly publishing process.

Comment: I removed the question about the size, if you have concerns/questions about this topic, please open a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy, it's the same as normal web apps: https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap#publishing-the-build-results…. For the package size, if you don't use AOT, a combination of the IL linker and Brotli compression is generally used.